# How to prove this polynomial is a solution of this functional equation?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, functional-equations

### Background:

We define $\omega(r) =  \text{number of distinct prime factors of } r$ and $\mu(r) =  \text{mobius function of } r$

### Conjecture

Then the solution to

$$ f(x) +  \sum_{r=2}^\infty \omega(r) (1 -\mu(r)^2 + \mu(r) )f(x^r) = x $$

is:

$$ f(x) = x + \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{p_r}$$

Where $p_i$ is the $i'th$ prime and this equation is defined in the interval $(-1,1)$ as $f(x)$ is convergent in that interval only.

### Method of verification (for finite number of terms)

Substituting $x=0$ in $ f(x) +  \sum_{r=2}^\infty \omega(r) (1 -\mu(r)^2 + \mu(r) )f(x^r) = x $:

We get $$f(0) = 0$$

Differentiating $ f(x) + \sum_{r=2}^\infty \omega(r) (1 -\mu(r)^2 + \mu(r) )f(x^r) = x $ and putting $x=0$ we get $$f'(0) = 1$$

We can differentiate $n$ times and substitute $x=0$ and find $f''^n(0) = ?$

Comment: Same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218948/how-to-prove-this-conjecture), with the comment about the function $f(x)$ (now deleted, unfortunately).

Comment: Yea, I realized I made a mistake in the previous post, u can verify the conjecture upto some finite number of terms and see it makes sense (I verified it for $x^{12}$)

Comment: Next time you could edit and modify the old question instead of reposting (basically the same) question. Also, you lost the upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\omega(1)=0$, you have
$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty \omega(r) (-1)^{\mu(r)}f(x^r) =
\sum_{r=2}^\infty \omega(r) (-1)^{\mu(r)}f(x^r) $$
and so no $x$ term appears at all (i.e., all terms in the expression
are of degree $2$ or greater).

Hence, it is not equal to $x$, so your $f$ is not the solution to this functional equation.

Comment: I've edited my question (made too many mistakes) but it's only valid in the range $(-1,1)$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous  My answer still applies: since $\omega(1)=0$, you have no terms of degree one in your sum, and so the expression is not equal to $x$.

Comment: Ah, my bad I thought $\omega(1) = 1$ ... but I've edited that part now ...

Comment: @MoreAnonymous It is still not correct.  Using GP, I find that your left-hand expression has a term $2x^8$, so it is not equal to $x$.